# Issues of choosing classmethod over inheritance in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, abstract-class, class-method

What are the main issues I can come across if I choose to use *classmethod* over *Inheritance* in Python? A *(silly)* example would be:

```
class Pizza(object):
    def __init__(self, ingredients):
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.cooked = False

    def cook(self):        
        print "cooking"
        self.cooked = True

    # A pepperoni pizza using a factory method
    @classmethod
    def Pepperoni(cls):
        return cls("pepperoni")

# An onion pizza inheriting from Pizza base class
class Onion(Pizza):
    def __init__(self):
        ingredient = "onion"
        super(Onion, self).__init__(ingredient)
```

I know that

- I cannot (easily) add custom methods to Pepperoni
- I cannot make Pizza an abstract base class

anything else?

Comment: Isn't pizza just some ingredients on top of it, why would it have to be *abstract* in the first place? What would a Pepperoni pizza do differently from an Onion pizza or an Onion pizza with added pepperoni?!

Comment: i.e. classmethods vs inheritance serve *completely* different purposes.

Comment: Do get to technical on pizzas please, it is just an example

Comment: Ok, if they serve *completely* different purposes, could you point out which are the main differences? I could make a `Pizza.Pepperoni()` and also a `Onion()` and both objects would have same methods and properties

Comment: This is totally wrong why the class method have to return an instance/class of same class. what do u acheive here ?

Comment: unless Julien Danjou is wrong, one purpose of classmethods in python is to make *factory methods*. See the *from_fridge()* method in https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think of `Pepperoni` as a class in its own right, just like `Onion`. Whereas `Onion` is a class, `Pepperoni` is just a function living on `Pizza`. Sure one should not think of `Pepperoni` as a normal method, but really it is. The `classmethod` decorator effectively turns the `Pepperoni` method into a factory function, producing a new instance. The code is completely equivalent to just writing the function outside of the class:

```
def Pepperoni():
    return Pizza("pepperoni")
```

You wouldn't talk about "adding custom methods to `Pepperoni`" now, but really nothing has changed.

Comment: Yes, I understand the difference between them, but I'm having a hard time trying to decide whether I should use inheritance or just make classmethods.. Imagine you have to code *Pizza* for a store which has a set of 30 different kinds, what would you do?

Comment: I would simply utilize the `ingredients` argument of `Pizza`: `pizza_with_onion = Pizza('onion')`. The factory function should be used if you somehow need to instantiate a pizza from something other than its ingredients. A whole new class would be needed if you decided also to make kebabs, which is different from a pizza but might still share quite a few methods.

Comment: Thanks mate! I guess making a factory class although I don't need to *instantiate a pizza from something other than its ingredients* doesn't make any harm =)